# Can I lower speed on 1/4 HP PSC fan motor by lowering the input voltage without harming motor?

Tags: motor, induction-motor, speed

I have pics of the motor label. This motor now has three speed settings: low, medium and high. I have pictures of the control as well.

Comment: You say you have pictures of the motor label, but I don't see them. Why didn't you put them in your question?

Comment: I assume you are planning on using a phase control to slow the motor down. This sort of works but will cause future problems. When it slows down you increase the slip in the motor causing it to get hot and generate a lot of harmonics. If you use a sine wave control it will slow down but it will behave very similarly. Use a VFD drive, that will work. Use the winding closest to the speed you want.

Comment: Thanks. Was planning on using a Triac (transformer) to lower voltage with the same 60 HZ frequency. Did not post pics because not sure how to do and thought I  could send to anyone who wants them.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably safely lower the speed by reducing the voltage with the motor on high speed setting. That should work if the motor is connected to the original fan. If you reduce the voltage too much, the motor may stall and could overheat if that happens. It is not a good idea to try to reduce the speed below the speed of original low speed setting.

Reducing the speed by reducing the voltage reduces the available torque. As a result, the fan's torque demand curve intersects the motor's torque supply curve at a lower speed. The fan's torque demand curve decreases with decreased speed as illustrated in my answer to [Speed control for PSC induction motor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/331092/speed-control-for-psc-induction-motor). As a result, the motor operates at a higher slip and increased rotor losses. However the motor requires much less torque, so that offsets the losses due to increased slip. Due to the decreased air flow, the fan is less effectively cooled. With several changes going on, it is difficult to predict whether or not the motor will overheat. I would operate it at the lowest speed with the switch and determine how hot the outside of the motor is. Then operate with reduced voltage and see if it gets hotter.

You have a comment recommendation to get a VFD. There are very few VFD manufacturers offering VFDs for single-phase motors. There are more with VFDs that accept single-phase input and provide 3-phase output. I would first consider a smaller fan or consider a fan with a 3-phase motor and a VFD.

Comment: Using this fan as a whole house fan (we call them attic fans) but would like to slow the fan down more than the low setting. (less airflow but quieter). The fan is attached directly to the motor shaft.

Comment: See addition to answer.

Comment: Sounds like you feel the only negative, other than stall, might be a increase in motor temperature. I believe it is thermal protected so I might try it once without damage. I would have to buy a triac though. I think it runs fairly cool on low speed.

Comment: I should have said Variac to lower voltage not Triac!