# Using a voltage regulator dimmer with a 220V water pump

Tags: motor, voltage-regulator, water

I am builgin a hydroponics vertical farm. The motor which I bought is too powerful (220V/100W) for my system so I want to reduce its power with using a voltage regulator dimmer.

My motor has a ground wire but the dimmer does not have ground input and output. Will there be a problem about that in the future? Do you have any other advice to reduce my motor's power?

[image: Voltage Regulator Dimmer]

Comment: A dimmer is designed to dim electrical lighting. The behavior of a motor is very dissimilar to that of a light, so you may have deeper issues than just ground wires.

Comment: Put a bypass valve around the pump.  Just open that valve, and the water will circulate at the pump and reduce flow to the plants.

Comment: The question lacks important details about the proposed system and what you are trying to accomplish. I have posted an answer that makes some assumptions and includes some qualifications that must be met to make the answer valid.

Answer (score 0):

The motor's ground wire should only be connected to the motor frame, not the motor windings. The motor power connection may have a power common connection that is connected to earth ground at the service entrance. If the controller is installed properly, it should be compatible with that. The controller needs to be installed in an enclosure. If the enclosure is metal, it needs to be grounded and the live parts of the enclosure must be adequately insulated from the enclosure.

You need to make sure that the motor and load are compatible with voltage control. For a centrifugal pump, that would mean the static head should be quite a bit lower than the dynamic head. Voltage control will probably not work with a positive-displacement pump.

Look at [Can I lower speed on 1/4 HP PSC fan motor by lowering the input voltage without harming motor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/575542/can-i-lower-speed-on-1-4-hp-psc-fan-motor-by-lowering-the-input-voltage-without) and [Speed control for PSC induction motor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/331092/speed-control-for-psc-induction-motor).

Answer (score 0):

I will take a SWAG and try to give you some answers that may help. It would be a big help if we knew what the motor was but since we don't...The device you picture is being sold as a motor speed control by some china suppliers. It does not have a third wire as it is not needed. Generally these are put in a enclosure preferably metal where the third wire (earth) is connected. They do work nicely with universal motors but not the others. Hint universal motors have brushes. If it does not have brushes they make a device called a VFD (Variable Frequency Drive) that changes the frequency of the AC rather than the voltage. This may work with your motor. rdtsc gave you the most economical advice and it is simple to operate. You should give that a try. This is much better than adding a restriction which would increase the pressure on the pump causing it to work harder and wear out sooner.

I have similar pumps and they control the flow by restricting the input. You can try that but the best and most stable solution would be a VFD, the output would be the most consistent.

Comment: My motor is: (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32903319440.html) I just want to reduce its power. Is this possible?

Comment: The VFD will change its speed changing the pump's output. Slower will cause it to move less water and have less pressure.

Answer (score 0):

> My motor is: (aliexpress.com/item/32903319440.html) I just want to reduce its power. Is this possible?

To control a motors speed, you need to use variable frequency drive (VFD). But of courese it really isn't a viable option as even the cheapest, chinese ones are going to cost you more than your pump.

Maybe buy a smaller pump? Those same Hailea pumps seem to be available in various wattages and are dirt cheap even at local resellers here in Europe,  smallest ones are under 20€.

Buy it from local seller so they can give you advise about what size to get and most importantly warranty/liability just in case it catches a fire etc.

Answer (score 0):

> My motor has a ground wire but the dimmer does not have ground input and output.

Make sure you connect the ground of the motor through to the ground of your electricity supply.  if the dimmer doesn't need a ground, that's fine.  Connect the ground wires together separately.