# How to use this motor

Tags: motor, motor-controller

I have this old motor laying around and I'd like to be able to use it. Mostly I would like to be able to control the speed.

[image]

Although, I'm not really sure what to use. Are there boards available? Can I plug it in a wall socket just like this? But then, how do I control the speed...

EDIT: Not visible on this picture but the only "input" the motor has is a 3 wire plug. Not sure it is useful.

Comment: This appears to be a standard 230V 50Hz single phase induction motor.  These can be speed controlled to a certain extent but the best way to is change the input frequency.  But you can only do so within certain limits due to the way these are designed.

Answer (score 0):

You can on the label that the motor requires 230 volts at 50 Hz AC power. It also requires a 3 microfarad capacitor that is rated 430 volts AC. The capacitor value compared to the 0.8 amp motor current requirement indicate that the motor is a single-phase motor of the permanent split capacitor (PSC) type. If the capacitor is not attached to the motor, you need to obtain a suitable capacitor and determine how it should be connected. Since there are only 3 wires coming out of the motor, you know that it must attach to two of those wires. Power needs to be connected between one of those two wires and the third wire.

If the plug that is connected to the motor is the type that plugs into the wall, and it was connected by someone who knew the proper connections, one of the three wires must be an earth/ground wire that is connected to the motor frame. The other two wires should be connected to the motor windings. The capacitor is either already attached or there is an attachment point that you have not discovered.

If the plug is the type that interconnects components inside an appliance, they all connect to the motor windings and the capacitor was attached somewhere inside the appliance from which the motor was removed.

The motor speed can not be controlled very satisfactorily. There are other answers to questions here that explain that. here is one of them: [Speed control for PSC induction motor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/331092/speed-control-for-psc-induction-motor)

Comment: On the left side of the picture, there is a grey round "thing" with a black cover below. Could this be the capacitor you are mentionning? because the wires are going "throught" that thing.

Comment: Yes, that could be the capacitor. Is there something printed on it?

Comment: I'll take a picture in a few minutes. in the meantime, is the following item a fit for controling the motor: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/controller-adjustable-control-switch-electric/dp/B0943YMXN8/ref=sr_1_28

Comment: I just had a look at it and it does not really require a picture, there a clear 3uF writing on it and 420V class A 470v class B indication so it seem to fit what you said

Comment: The linked Amazon item is not suitable the output id DC rather than AC.