# Electric Fan Power Consumption

Tags: power

I am not sure but I believe the usual electric-fan switches its resistance value to change the power output.

**Q1.** With that case, does the resistor consumes the power?

**Q2.** Do switch #1, #2 and #3 consume same amount of power?

If the answer for both Q1 and Q2 are true, then turning the electric-fan to #1 doesn't save much energy compared to turning it to #3?

Comment: Schematic required.

Comment: Show a schematic, edit your question and use the schematic tool

Comment: I don't have an schematic. I just assumed that the conventional electric-fan uses resistance as switch, well based on the answer below, my guess was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are talking about ceiling fans and regular desktop fans, then No, it is not a change in resistance. 
Check this thread for explanations on speed switches for electric appliance motors

[Calculating the capacitor values to control ceiling fan speed](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/217828/calculating-the-capacitor-values-to-control-ceiling-fan-speed)

This thread also covers the topic in detail
https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16620/how-do-i-shut-off-the-ceiling-fan-without-a-pull-chain